# Overfull \hbox ( too wide) for \newenvironment

Tags: environments

I've made a \newenvironment in my documentment class. But if I make a \pagebreak or just reach the end of a page I get the warning "Overfull \hbox (0.38pt too wide)"

My \newenvironment is

```
\newenvironment{appendices}
    {
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \def\thesection{\Alph{section}}
    \numberwithin{page}{section}
    \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}
    {
    \iftoggle{is_danish}{%If
        \cfoot{Side \thepage\ af \pageref{LastPage3}}
    }{%Else
    \cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage3}}
    }%Endif
    }
}
```

Here is an example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

%Packages
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    %Conditionals, if, else
    \newtoggle{is_danish}
    \newtoggle{is_english}
\setlength{\headheight}{27.3pt} 


\newenvironment{appendices}
    {
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \def\thesection{\Alph{section}}
    \numberwithin{page}{section}
    \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}
    {
    \iftoggle{is_danish}{%If
        \cfoot{Side \thepage\ af \pageref{LastPage3}}
    }{%Else
    \cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage3}}
    }%Endif
    }
}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{fancy}
% A buch of text, equations and figures
\begin{appendices}

    \section{Matlab code}
    \subsection{Post-processing}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum

    \label{LastPage3}
    \newpage
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way i can remove this warning?

Comment: You are missing a {} at the end (for the closing "section" of the environment). Also we are missing all the rest needed code to play arround with it and help you (I mean this: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) . Welcome to TeX.SE! And the warning, doesn't seem to comes from your provided code.

Comment: In addition to the major issue pointed out by @koleygr, your definition also introduces spaces which you likely don't want here. I'd recommend using Babel (or Polyglossia) to manage different languages, as that will give you a lot more power and flexibility than a home-grown Boolean.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question to make it a complete document! Now when I try it, I get errors (maybe you removed too many packages?) because `\numberwithin` is not defined, neither is `\iftoggle` (and actually nor is `\cfoot`). Could you change your example into one that actually compiles successfully, and for which you get the error?

Comment: (I think you may need a few packages (`fancyhdr` for `\cfoot`, `amsmath` for `\numberwithin`) and remove the `is_danish` (or define it, after adding `etoolbox` package). But then the file does not result in the overfull hbox error, so it is not an example at all.)

Comment: Sorry about the slow start. It's my first time posting.
I had a hard time recreating the error. Turns out it is only present when the table of content is in the document too.
@koleygr I'm not sure where you're referring to regarding the {}? And thanks for the link, it's a great guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is

```
(./aa316.toc
Overfull \hbox (0.38747pt too wide) detected at line 2
 \OT1/cmr/m/n/12 A-0
```

Showing that it is the A-0 on line 2 of the toc that is too wide for the alloted space.

In the standard classes that space is `\@pnumwidth` and so making that a bit bigger removes the warning, adding this to your preamble for example

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{2em}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I changed it to \@pnumwidth{3em} for my bigger document, but it worked! Thank you very much